# Using both IIS6 and IIS7 with the same SQL State Server

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, state-server

We are trying to use new IIS7 (32bit, Classic Mode) webs in addition to our IIS6 webs with one SQL State Server for ASP.NET Session Handling. Unfortunately the number of transactions per seconds in the State Servers spikes (10 times+) as soon as we add the new IIS7 web to the farm.

Are there any known issues with the described setup?